# input text from a file to a char variable

Tags: c++, char, fstream

I have a variable

```
ifstream inFile("stuff.txt");
```

in the stuff.txt file there's a full sentance:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

How do I put it into a char array with all the spaces?

```
char text[250];
inFile >> text;
```

gets me to the first space, nothing else.

Comment: Here 250 is what we would call a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants).  Is there really anything about the number 250 (or in zero-terminated strings, the effective number 249) that your program needs to be mixed up with?  Using a `std::string` which can gracefully handle resizing is a much better and safer idea.  See ["Learning Standard C++ as a New Language"](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf) for some insights...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ifstream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) to read into a `char` array or use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read into a `std::string`. When you use `inFile >> text` whitespace will act as a delimiter, which is why it stops at the first space.

Using `std::getline()` to read into a `std::string` removes the requirement for specifying the maximum number of characters to read. This removes the potential for buffer overruns and avoids the added complexity of coping with partially read lines (if a line was `> 250` in this case for example).

Always check the result of IO operations immediately:

```
 std::ifstream inFile("stuff.txt");
 if (inFile.is_open())
 {
     std::string line;
     if (std::getline(inFile, line))
     {
         // Use 'line'.
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!inFile.eof()) {

    inFile >> text;

 }
```